# PDO не работает запрос

Tags: php, pdo

```
$post_title = 'something';
$sql = 'SELECT title FROM `posts` WHERE title = :title';
$data_request = $this->dbase->prepare($sql);
$data_request->bindParam(':title', $post_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$data_request->execute();
$result = $data_request->fetch();
echo ($result) ? '+' : '-';
```

Проблема заключается в том, что пересмотрел множество постов здесь же, и на php.net смотрел в первую очередь, но мой код ни в какую не хочет находить запись с нужным тайтлом, хотя она существует, делал такой напрямую в бд запрос и все нормально выдавало, уже не знаю, что и делать. Помогите хотя бы сузить круг поиска, кстати пост с числовым названием находит.
Подключение к бд работает 100%.

Comment: `->execute([':title' => $post_title])` без `bindParam` пробовали? Что за база?

Comment: Кодировки в переменной и в базе совпадают?

Comment: Без bindParam пробовал, никак не помогает. @vp_arth

Comment: Попробуйте ещё неименованный плейсхолдер: `title = ?` и `execute([$post_title])` И таки скажите, что за драйвер, `pdo_mysql`?

Comment: Проблема была таки в кодировке строки, спс за наводку. @vp_arth

Comment: не забрасывайте вопрос так, напишите ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась после установки кодировки:

```
$this->dbase->exec("set names utf8");
```

Comment: Кодировку прописывайте в dsn `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');` или даже `charset=utf8mb4`, если у вас MySQL 5.5.3 и выше.